# Rails 4 has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Hi there I'm a rails newbie and am having a hard time understanding an error I am getting.

I have many to many relationship that consists of

1. Project -> one to many project_numbers (billing numbers)
2. project_number -> has id, project_id(fk), task_name and hours associated with a task.
3. Associate-> Employee/Developer performing work (id, name, ...)
4. Resource -> Join table containing ID, project_number_id (fk) and Associate_id (fk), hrs assigned, hours used

My Model is as follows

```
#project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'projects'
  belongs_to :client, :inverse_of => :project
  has_many :project_numbers
end

#associate.rb
class Associate < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'associates'
  has_many :resources
  #has_many :project_numbers, through: => :resources
end

#project_number.rb
class ProjectNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'project_numbers'
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :project_number
  has_many :resources
  #has_many :associates, through: => :resources
end

resource.rb
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'resources'
  belongs_to :project_number
  belongs_to :associate
end
```

Each time I uncomment the "has_many through" lines I receive an error viewing the project details page (show):

My show.html.erb has a the line highlighted

```
    <dt>Project Hours: </dt> <dd><%= @project.project_numbers.sum(:hours_sold)%></dd>
```

With a rails error of:
/home/ruby/pda/app/models/project_number.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected =>
  has_many :associates, through: => :resources

I have been through many blogs and think I have the relationship set up correctly however I don't understand the error at all.  Why would a call to sum(hours) in project_number cause be triggering this error.  Note: even with this line commented the next query against project_numbers fails. Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is syntactically wrong.

```
has_many :project_numbers, through: => :resources #wrong
```

This is the right syntax

```
has_many :project_numbers, :through => :resources # right
```

For **Rails4**,you can write it to

```
has_many :project_numbers, through: :resources
```

Do the same changes to the other association too.

Comment: Thank you,  I think I had the Rails4 format at one time but something else wasn't right.  This works perfectly now.  Thank you for taking the time to respond to my post :)